# Calculate frequency of column in data frame using spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get the Frequency of distinct values in a Spark dataframe column, something like "value_counts" from Python Pandas. By frequency I mean, the highest occurring value in a table column (such as rank 1 value, rank 2, rank 3 etc. In the expected output, 1 has occurred 9 times in column a, so it has topmost frequency.

I'm using Spark SQL but it is not working out, may be because of the reduce operation I have written is wrong.

```
   **Pandas Example**
  value_counts().index[1]

  **Current Code in Spark** 
   val x=  parquetRDD_subset.schema.fieldNames

  val dfs = x.map(field => spark.sql
  (s"select 'ParquetRDD' as TableName, 
  '$field' as column,
  min($field) as min, max($field) as max,
  SELECT number_cnt FROM (SELECT $field as value,
  approx_count_distinct($field) as number_cnt FROM peopleRDDtable 
  group by $field) as frequency from peopleRDDtable"))

  val withSum = dfs.reduce((x, y) => x.union(y)).distinct()

   withSum.show()
```

The problem area is with query below.

```
  SELECT number_cnt FROM (SELECT $field as value,
  approx_count_distinct($field) as number_cnt FROM peopleRDDtable 
  group by $field)

  **Expected output** 

   TableName   | column  | min  | max   | frequency1 |
  _____________+_________+______+_______+____________+
  ParquetRDD   | a       | 1    | 30    |    9       |
 _____________+_________+______+_______+____________+
  ParquetRDD   | b       | 2    | 21    |    5       |
```

How do I solve this ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue with below with using `count($field)` instead of `approx_count_distinct($field)`. Then I used `Rank` analytical function to get the `first rank` of value. It worked.